# How can I connect two inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I need to connect the inputs like the gif below

[image]

I wrote this code but because it works based on an idea, I can only have three inputs (pricing-base-price, pricing-profit, pricing-set-price) and if I want to have three more inputs with the same class, there will be a problem. My site address: **[alomykar.ir/qw](https://alomykar.ir/qw)**
Codes used

```js
function calculateProfit(val) {
  var baseCost = document.getElementById("baseCost").value;
  document.getElementById("Profit").value = (val - baseCost).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="prt-pricing-heading">
  <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
  <div class="pricing-field"><input id="SalePrice" class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00" onchange="calculateProfit(this.value);" oninput="calculateProfit(this.value)"></div>
</div>
<div class="prt-pricing-detial">
  <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
  <div class="pricing-field"><input id="baseCost" class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
</div>
<div class="prt-pricing-detial">
  <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
  <div class="pricing-field"><input id="Profit" class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make this code work for multiple copies of these three inputs in the same page?

Comment: You can't use the same id for more than 1 input.

Comment: yes @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: How can I do this? Is there a solution? @jqueryHtmlCSS

Comment: You need a make dynamic jquery for running other proccess

Comment: Please give an example @Adhitya

Comment: Do you want to change 6 inputs?  What are the classes and ids of these?  Attempt to create a function and put some jquery or javascript code in that function to change the values.  Or, is that what calculateProfit is for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes instead of IDs, and wrap the inputs in another element (`.pricing-input`). Then you can iterate over them and set event listeners for each element:

```js
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.pricing-input')) {
  const setPrice = elem.querySelector('.pricing-set-price')
  const basePrice = elem.querySelector('.pricing-base-price')
  const profit = elem.querySelector('.pricing-profit')
  setPrice.addEventListener('input', function calculateProfit() {
    profit.value = (setPrice.value - basePrice.value).toFixed(2);
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" value="14.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To calculate the default value immediately, just call the `calculateProfit` function:

```js
for (const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.pricing-input')) {
  const setPrice = elem.querySelector('.pricing-set-price')
  const basePrice = elem.querySelector('.pricing-base-price')
  const profit = elem.querySelector('.pricing-profit')
  function calculateProfit() {
    profit.value = (setPrice.value - basePrice.value).toFixed(2);
  }
  calculateProfit()
  setPrice.addEventListener('input', calculateProfit)
}
```

```html
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="pricing-input">
  <div class="prt-pricing-heading">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your sale price:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-set-price" type="number" value="24.00"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Product base Cost:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-base-price" type="number" value="10.00" disabled></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prt-pricing-detial">
    <span class="pricing-heading">Your profit:</span>
    <div class="pricing-field"><input class="pricing-profit" type="number" disabled></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more info about some features used:

- [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: dont work , plase chack the this link :http://alomykar.ir/aaa/

Comment: @cdk Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096571/8376184) on how to include the script on page load

Comment: The problem was solved, but the amount of profit will not be calculated until the amount of input changes. Please see my page [link](http://alomykar.ir/qw)

Comment: @cdk I've edited my post to include that. However, non-trivial follow-up questions should generally be asked as separate questions, by the means of how SO works.